# Filter does not show as I expected

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I made a table that displays values from an array, to which I added a filter. The table is paginated with a maximum of 5 records per page.

The problem occurs when I apply the filter. For example, if you do a search for the term "ora" will have three records, one on each page.

How do these results to display together (on one page, or how many pages it needs, but not dissipated) and when I remove the filter to display it normal (in all pages)?

The live code is available here: https://plnkr.co/edit/QIcmQUqABDJcV3H6vqRo?p=preview

HTML:

```
<body ng-app="salariesApp" ng-controller="mainCtrl">
    <table class="table">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th ng-click="sortBy(id)">Nr. crt.</th>
                <th ng-click="sortBy(an)">Anul</th>
                <th ng-click="sortBy('den')">Denumirea institutiei/companiei</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td class="tableSearch"></td>
                <td class="tableSearch"><input class="form-control" type="text" id="inputYear" ng-model="searchSal.an" ng-value={{crrYear}} /></td>
                <td class="tableSearch"><input class="form-control" type="text" id="inputName" ng-model="searchSal.den" /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr ng-repeat="rows in showSal | filter: searchSal | orderBy: sortProperty: !reverse | filter : paginate track by $index">
                <td class="spa-col-md-1">{{rows.id}}</td>
                <td class="spa-col-md-2">{{rows.an}}</td>
                <td class="col-md-5">{{rows.den}}</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>

    <pagination total-items="totalItems" ng-model="currentPage" max-size="5" boundary-links="true"
        items-per-page="numPerPage" class="pagination-sm">
    </pagination>
</body>
```

JS:

```
var app = angular.module("salariesApp", ['ui.bootstrap']);

app.constant("appConst", {
    pagesLimit:             5,
    crrYear:                    2016
});

app.controller('mainCtrl', ['$scope', 'appConst', function($scope, appConst) {  
    $scope.crrYear = appConst.crrYear;

    $scope.pageNum = {
        linkBtnClass: 'linkBtnClass cursor-pointer'
    };

    $scope.showSal = [
        { id: '1', an: '2016', den: 'Oracle Romania' },
        { id: '2', an: '2016', den: 'Microsoft' },
        { id: '3', an: '2016', den: 'Computer Generated Solutions - CGS Europe' },
        { id: '4', an: '2016', den: 'IBM' },
        { id: '5', an: '2016', den: 'Luxoft' },
        { id: '6', an: '2016', den: 'Oracle Romania' },
        { id: '7', an: '2016', den: 'Luxoft' },
        { id: '8', an: '2016', den: 'Computer Generated Solutions - CGS Europe' },
        { id: '9', an: '2016', den: 'IBM' },
        { id: '10', an: '2016', den: 'Luxoft' },
        { id: '11', an: '2016', den: 'Oracle Romania' },
        { id: '12', an: '2016', den: 'Microsoft' },
        { id: '13', an: '2016', den: 'IBM' },
        { id: '14', an: '2016', den: 'Luxoft' }
    ];

    $scope.searchSal = '';

    $scope.sortProperty = $scope.showSal.id;
    $scope.reverse = true;
    $scope.sortBy = function (sortProperty) {
        $scope.reverse = ($scope.sortProperty === sortProperty) ? !$scope.reverse : false;
        $scope.sortProperty = sortProperty;
    };



    // PAGINATION:
    $scope.totalItems = $scope.showSal.length;
    $scope.currentPage = 1;
    $scope.numPerPage = 5;

    $scope.paginate = function(value) {
        var begin, end, index;
        begin = ($scope.currentPage - 1) * $scope.numPerPage;
        end = begin + $scope.numPerPage;
        index = $scope.showSal.indexOf(value);
        return (begin <= index && index < end);
    };


    $scope.getOptionsClass = function (index) {
        if (index > 0) {
            return 'thumbnail nav-option-r';
        } else {
            return 'thumbnail nav-option-l';
        }
    };
}]);
```

Comment: Your Plunker is broken.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've done some changes to your live version to achieve what you want. Check the following link:
//plnkr.co/edit/TZ1woevPK8uLlbERBtlR?p=preview

The reason why your version doesn't work is that the filter only do filter job to decide if the model's meet the condition BUT NOT to change the model. If there's no changes happens to model, then there won't has any changes for pagination or the table list.

So what I've done is just create a copy version of the original model and add watcher to that. You can find further information if plnkr link I've attached abbove.

Comment: Thanks, this is what I want to do :) ... But I have another question, how I can make to sort all data, not only data from a single page? Like did @Lex: when it clicked on "nr crt" will sort all table, not only the page, how it is in my case...

Comment: Still the similar way as I've mentioned. You need to change the model. Here's the live version I made, you can check it by yourself. [link](http://plnkr.co/edit/4ccycImFtIQjI53RhKIu?p=preview)

Answer (score 1):

I adapted this from [this JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2ZzZB/56/) which is listed on the [Angular JSFiddle Examples page of the wiki](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/wiki/JsFiddle-Examples). I couldn't figure out your pagination so I just put buttons on there, but you should be able to extrapolate and apply this to your pagination functionality. By applying the filter which simply removes the elements from the array that are not displayed on the current page and using `limitTo` pagination becomes very easy and doesn't exhibit the behavior you were seeing where each item would display on its own page.

```js
var app = angular.module("salariesApp", ['ui.bootstrap']);

app.constant("appConst", {
  pagesLimit: 5,
  crrYear: 2016
});

app.filter('startFrom', function() {
    return function(input, start) {
        start = +start; //parse to int
        return input.slice(start);
    }
});

app.controller('mainCtrl', ['$scope', '$filter', 'appConst',
      function($scope, $filter, appConst) {
        $scope.crrYear = appConst.crrYear;

        $scope.pageNum = {
          linkBtnClass: 'linkBtnClass cursor-pointer'
        };

        $scope.showSal = [{ id: '1', an: '2016', den: 'Oracle Romania' }, 
                          { id: '2', an: '2016', den: 'Microsoft' }, 
                          { id: '3', an: '2016', den: 'Computer Generated Solutions - CGS Europe' }, 
                          { id: '4', an: '2016', den: 'IBM' }, 
                          { id: '5', an: '2016', den: 'Luxoft' }, 
                          { id: '6', an: '2016', den: 'Oracle Romania' }, 
                          { id: '7', an: '2016', den: 'Luxoft' }, 
                          { id: '8', an: '2016', den: 'Computer Generated Solutions - CGS Europe' }, 
                          { id: '9', an: '2016', den: 'IBM' }, 
                          { id: '10', an: '2016', den: 'Luxoft' }, 
                          { id: '11', an: '2016', den: 'Oracle Romania' }, 
                          { id: '12', an: '2016', den: 'Microsoft' }, 
                          { id: '13', an: '2016', den: 'IBM' }, 
                          { id: '14', an: '2016', den: 'Luxoft' }];

        $scope.searchSal = {};

        $scope.sortProperty = $scope.showSal.id;
        $scope.reverse = true;
        $scope.sortBy = function(sortProperty) {
          $scope.reverse = ($scope.sortProperty === sortProperty) ? !$scope.reverse : false;
          $scope.sortProperty = sortProperty;
        };

        // PAGINATION:
        $scope.totalItems = ($filter('filter')($scope.showSal, $scope.searchSal)).length;
        $scope.currentPage = 0;
        $scope.numPerPage = 5;
        
        $scope.totalPages = function() {
          return Math.ceil(($filter('filter')($scope.showSal, $scope.searchSal)).length / $scope.numPerPage);
        };
      }]);
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.css" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.0.0/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.7/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui-bootstrap/2.0.0/ui-bootstrap-tpls.min.js"></script>

<div ng-controller="mainCtrl" ng-app="salariesApp">
  <table class="table">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th ng-click="sortBy(id)">Nr. crt.</th>
        <th ng-click="sortBy(an)">Anul</th>
        <th ng-click="sortBy('den')">Denumirea institutiei/companiei</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td class="tableSearch"></td>
        <td class="tableSearch">
          <input type="text" ng-value="{{crrYear}}" ng-model="searchSal.an" id="inputYear" class="form-control" />
        </td>
        <td class="tableSearch">
          <input type="text" ng-model="searchSal.den" id="inputName" class="form-control" />
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr ng-repeat="rows in showSal | filter: searchSal | orderBy: sortProperty: !reverse |  startFrom:currentPage * numPerPage | limitTo: numPerPage track by $index">
        <td class="spa-col-md-1">{{rows.id}}</td>
        <td class="spa-col-md-2">{{rows.an}}</td>
        <td class="col-md-5">{{rows.den}}</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
  <button ng-click="currentPage = currentPage - 1" ng-disabled="currentPage === 0">Prev</button> Page {{currentPage + 1}} of {{totalPages()}} <button ng-click="currentPage = currentPage + 1" ng-disabled="currentPage === totalPages() -1">Next</button>
</div>
```

Comment: It works, but with a little thing in minus... if try to search from page 2-3 the term "ora" it will show nothing until you will go manually forward (with click) to page 1 and then it changes (how it is normal) the total pages to 1. Now I try to make that to change the current page if it is higher like total pages... but I can not manage the view...

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem with searching from 2nd page with a simple condition:

```
app.filter('startFrom', function () {
        return function (input, start, crrPage, totalPages) {
                if (crrPage+1 <= totalPages) {
                    start = +start; //parse to int
                } else {
                    crrPage = 0;
                    start = +crrPage; //parse to int
                }
                return input.slice(start);
        }
});
```

And with this condition I make it to change the current page to real current page on searching:

```
$scope.showCrrPage = function (crrPage) {
    if ((crrPage+1) <= $scope.totalPages()) {
        return $scope.currentPage + 1;
    } else {
        return 1;
    }
}
```